# Why is Wine not seeing that I have mono 3 installed?

Tags: ubuntu, wine, mono-framework

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 64bit. Does anyone have an idea why the following might be happening?

```
# wine --version  
wine-1.4.1  

# mono --version  
Mono JIT compiler version 3.0.6 (Debian 3.0.6+dfsg-1~exp1~pre1)  
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com   

# wine application.exe  
wine: Install Mono 2.8 or greater for Windows to run .NET 4.0 applications.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is lies in the old version of [WINE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29). A newer version of WINE will recognize mono framework version 3.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was upgrading Wine to a newer version (at least v1.7).

Answer (score 0):

As for workaround, you can install .NET instead by using `winetricks`, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
winetricks dotnet45
```